# PHP Live File Reading

Tags: php

I am making a simple live chat with php but I am making it so it reads and writes to a text file instead of mysql (already made a live chat with mysql). How could I recursively read the text files content without it constantly reloading. I would like it so it only reloads if it recognises a change. Code:

```
<?php
        $linesOld = 0;
        $linesNew = 0;
        $myfile = fopen("chat.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

        $linesNew = filesize("chat.txt");

        if ($linesNew > 0 && $linesOld != $linesNew) {
            while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
                if (strpos($line, "#clear#") !== false) {
                    file_put_contents("chat.txt", "");
                    header("refresh: 1;");
                }

                echo $line;
                echo "<br>";
            }

            $linesOld = filesize("chat.txt");
        }

        fclose($myfile);
        ?>
```

Comment: You'd need AJAX, or better still websockets, to handle the transmission of the data between browser and serer, if you want to avoid your page reloading. That has nothing to do with whether you use a file or a database as the backend storage.

Comment: I have never used AJAX. How would I do that?

Comment: ^ That's a very broad question. I'd recommend doing research on it first and coming back with a specific question.

Comment: Start by finding some tutorials and learning the basics. Then come back to us if you get stuck on something specific in your own implementation.

Comment: One question. How do I install AJAX with using `sudo php -S localhost:80`?

Comment: I must have typed the code in wrong. 

Comment: If you have a problem with your Ajax code please ask a new question about that specifically